# Apache HTTPClient 4.3.3 execute method for a GET request blocks and never returns

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Facing this weird issue since morning, I am making a REST call to a particular endpoint which gives responses in pages so i need to make calls again and again until all pages are completed. My code works fine and dandy until the last page after the last page the next request I make (which should return a blank page) by `httpClient.execute(httpGet);` is blocked permanently and never comes back or neither throws any exception. If I set connection request time out then the last call is not blocked and fails saying timeout but I am not getting why that last call is not working **If I make the same last call from firefox RESTClient it works**. Kindly help.

I also tried adding different log levels like `System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");` and other logs to debug but no luck.

Below is my code.

```
private static Servers fetchServers(String token,String endpoint) throws Exception{
    JsonReader jreader = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
    try{
        URI uri = new URI(endpoint);

        /** accepting all certificates */
        httpClient = getSecuredHttpClient();

        uri = new URIBuilder(uri)
                .setParameter("limit", "1")//Page limit, for testing have kept just 1 since i have only 2 records.
                .build();

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);

        httpGet.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        httpGet.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", token);
        httpGet.setHeader("accept", "application/json");
        httpGet.setHeader(HTTP.USER_AGENT, "python-neutronclient");

        Servers cloudServers = new Servers();
        cloudServers.setServers(new ArrayList<Server>());

        boolean nextPage = false;

        do {
                HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);//this is where it gets blocked for last page.
                if(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent());
                    jreader = new JsonReader(isr);
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Address.class, new AddressAdapter()).create();

                    Servers servers = gson.fromJson(jreader, Servers.class);
                    cloudServers.getServers().addAll(servers.getServers());

                    if(servers.getServersLinks() == null || servers.getServersLinks().size()==0)
                        nextPage = false;
                    else if(servers.getServersLinks().get(0).getRel().equals("next"))
                        nextPage = true;

                    uri = new URI(servers.getServersLinks().get(0).getHref());//this gives the url for next page.
                    httpGet.setURI(uri);
                }else{
                    break;
                }
        } while (nextPage);
        return cloudServers;
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }finally{
        if(null != jreader){
            jreader.close();
        }
        if(null != isr){
            isr.close();
        }
        if(null != httpClient){
            httpClient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has the server on the other end flushed() the stream?

Comment: in the do while, after "httpGet.setURI(uri)"  try to print the URI and then you know the URI where it blocks. then try to see execute a little test with that URI alone . does it still hang? do you see anything unusual about its value?

Comment: @LanceJava No, if i do the same pagination through REST client it perfectly works fine.

Comment: @A.J. actually i had debug logs to print out each and every step just removed to make the code small and clear here before posting. all the uris which are being hit are valid and working endpoints. don't know what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am fairly sure that your code simply leaks and eventually runs out of connections.

```
do {
    CloseableHttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    try {

    // Do what you have to do 
    // but make sure the response gets closed no matter what
    // even if do not care about its content

    } finally {
        resp.close();
    }        
} while (nextPage);
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg yup you are right i will make sure to add that, but this is not what is causing the issue here since i make only 3 page requests and the last request is blocking.

Comment: @willsteel: httpclient has a two connection per route limit by default. It takes 3 requests to exhaust the pool and to cause it to lock ;-)

Comment: wow! I definetly didnt knew about this two connection per route limit,as you suggested I used CloseableHTTPResponse and it worked like charm. Thanks Oleg :)

Comment: I have one more issue I am trying to hit an endpoint which is over SSL and I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate not verified.` exception, is there any custom configuration I need to do to the http client? If i accept all the certificates with some dummy trust manager it works fine but that's not what I want to do any suggestions?

Comment: @willsteel: you need to set up SSL context appropriately, for instance, by initializing with specific trust material or by using a custom trust strategy. See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e436

Comment: from the chapter I understand that I need to load a valid keystore in order for a successful connection, but how to get this keystore I am trying to hit pubilc HP Cloud Server how should I know about their server certificates? Excuse my ignorance in SSL and Security :)

Comment: @willsteel: the use of SSL usually implies that one knows what cert authorities or services one want to trust and what kind of key material one needs to use to authenticate. Generally HP is expected to provide you with such key material if key authentication is mandatory. I suspect though that your trust material is wrong and that is what causes the exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48689/discussion-between-willsteel-and-oleg)

Comment: As of Java 7, you can `try(CloseableHttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet))` but make sure you consume the response before exiting the `try` block.